# What is [2:] need for?

Tags: python, list

In my code there is a line:

**charInBinary = str(bin(ord(MESSAGE[i])))[2:]**

> What is [2:] need for?

Comment: If the output starts with `0b`, and you don't want that, you strip it off.

Comment: You should know it if you wrote the code.

Comment: Have you tried it without? Should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 3):

The `[2: ]` is [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing), and since that's being performed on a `str`, it means that you're retrieving all of the characters of the string starting at index 2. In this case, that's getting rid of `0b`.

Comment: Thanks a lot that help me figure it out

Answer (score 0):

`bin` returns a string with a leading `0b` prefix.  The `[2:]` is snipping off the prefix, leaving only the binary digits

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple question.

Without `[2:]` your output starts with `0b`, So for removing this we use this `[2:]`

```py
charInBinary = str(bin(ord(MESSAGE[i])))
print(charInBinary) # 0b111111

# WIth [2:]
charInBinary = str(bin(ord(MESSAGE[i])))[2:]
print(charInBinary) # 111111
```